# Java 8 interface doubts

Tags: java, interface

Still don't get why Java allow default implementation in interface, is that violating design principles that a contract should stay as contract? Any example to.explain?

Comment: JLS 9.4.3: '`default` method has a block body. This block of code provides an implementation of the method in the event that a class implements the interface but does not provide its own implementation of the method.' I don't see that any other explanation is necessary. Examples don't explain things, and language designers don't always obey other people's design principles.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, this feature was added to make it possible to modify an interface without having to rebuild every other class that implements it. I guess this is particularly apposite when building programs out of collections of libraries, all of which are maintained independently.

So I can add a new method to an interface and, so long as it has a default, classes that implement the interface will still work as before. With a default implementation, I would have had to amend and recompile every class that implemented the interface.

This feature doesn't necessarily violate the interface-as-contract principle, because classes that implement the interface still satisfy the contract, *so far as it applies to the methods they actually implement*. You can still read the interface, and know what constraints the implementing class has to satisfy.

All the same, it does seem to me that this feature exists for pragmatic reasons, and not because there is a sound software engineering reason to recommend it. I suspect that the differences between interfaces with defaults, and abstract classes, are quite subtle; I wonder what reasons one would have for choosing the former over the latter in *new* code?

Answer (score 1):

Default method are important in the updating process of interfaces.
If an interface has a set of methods, they all **must be implemented** by everyone wants use that interface.
 If the interface need to be extended adding a new method, the consumers of the interface have to implement also this new method and they are forced to change their code.
Using a default method, the manager of the interface can define a *default implementation* for a method; the consumer that want implement it is free to override it or use the implementation already provided; at the same time, another consumer that doesn't need the new method can simply ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Before Java 8 interface does not have any default implementation so if any class A implements the interface it has to implement all the methods of an interface. And after that if there is need to change in the application design and to add more methods in an existing interface then it is cumbersome because all the child classes have to implement these new methods. As interface grows old, the number of classes implementing it might grow to an extent that it is not possible to extend interfaces.

But in **Java 8** interface methods have default implementation. When a class A will implement an interface it is not mandatory to provide an implementation for default methods of interface. So now its easy to extend the growth of an interface. We can add more methods in interface by just giving default implementation. All classes just do not need to implement newly added methods.

For example:

```
public interface InteraceExample {

    default void log(String logMessage) {
        System.out.println("I1 logging::"+str);
    }
}
```